# Any official reference for client license requirement of OOS?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, oos, license

I am sorry but I failed to find any official reference about Office Online Server client license.

We have a SP2016 farm and are planning to add OOS servers. Our users have MS Office 2016 license but I heard (yes, from rumor) Office 365 license is required for OOS use.

Could you please point me to the official reference about OOS user license requirement?

Also, if only part of users (let's say 100 out of 400) have the licenses on OOS. Other users without license are readonly. Could I set the limitation on our farm?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the document here: [Licensing Microsoft Office software in Volume Licensing.](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/D/4/3D42BDC2-6725-4B29-B75A-A5B04179958B/Licensing_Microsoft_Office_Software.pdf)

Referring to the document:

> Office suite licenses with Software Assurance allow you to edit Office
> files using the Office Online Server from the licensed device. Users
> licensed for Office 365 ProPlus can also edit files using Office
> Online Server.

If you have MS Office 2016 license, you will have both view and Edit rights in OOS. Office 365 license is not a prerequisite.

> Office suite licenses with Software Assurance are only required for
> those employees editing Office Online Server documents.

There is no need to “set the limitation”, just assign licenses to those who need the Edit permission would do.

Comment: The wording is `Office suite licenses with Software Assurance` but I do not have SA. Is it fit?

Comment: @MarkL You will need Software Assurance for an Office suite license acquired through Commercial Licensing in order to edit Office documents in Microsoft Office Online Server. That’s recorded in the document as well.

Comment: I do not have SA and cannot acquire it. Can I purchase `Office 365 ProPlus` or any of M365 plan to cover it?

Comment: @MarkL Yes, license for Office 365 ProPlus will do.

Comment: how can we purchase Office 365 ProPlus?

Comment: @MarkL Office 365 Pro Plus is now renamed to Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise, which can be purchased via this entrance: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/microsoft-365-apps-for-enterprise-product

Comment: I am going to purchase M365 E1 plan for this purpose. Are you able to make Microsoft update their website to confirm? There is no official reference that up-to-date.

Comment: @MarkL I’m afraid that is beyond my ability. You can check out this document for reference on the name change though: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/name-change